# dart_pdf Image is not generated properly and how to use async function while generating multipage with image

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

Image not loading properly broken image

```
   PdfImage image = new PdfImage.file(
                doc.document,
                bytes: (File(field.imagename).readAsBytesSync()),
              );
```

How to use await getContentlist function as async. below function call

```
doc.addPage(
       pw.MultiPage(
        maxPages: 100,
        pageTheme: _buildTheme(
          pageFormat,
          
        ),
        header: _buildheader2,
        footer: _buildfooter2,
        build:  (pw.Context context)  => getContentlist(context),
      ),
    );
```

Here is the function

```
List<pw.Widget> getContentlist(context) {
      List<pw.Widget> contentlist = [];
      contentlist.add(pw.SizedBox(height: 20));

      contentlist.add(_contentheader2(context));                                                    
      return contentlist;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! please share getContentList as well

Comment: List<pw.Widget> getContentlist(context) {
      List<pw.Widget> contentlist = [];
      contentlist.add(pw.SizedBox(height: 20));

      contentlist.add(_contentheader2(context));                                                    
 return contentlist;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to ask 2 different questions

For the second part if `build` is not related with Flutter widget `build()` method you can just modify you snippet to make it async

```
build:  (pw.Context context) async  => getContentlist(context),
```

But if it relates to widget build - you need to use FutureBuilder widget which wait for Future state changes and rebuilds widgets

```
      FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _yourFuture, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // return widget that shows data
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            // return widget that shows  erro
          } 
          // by default show progress indication
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
          );
        },
      ),
```

PS feel free to reach me in comments

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I will try that. Can you help regarding the pdf issue. I can use the asset image for pdf generation using PdfImage test = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
      pdf: doc.document,
      image: const AssetImage('assets/img/test.jpg'),
    );    But the image broken in pdf from internal storage with 1st code on question. Its image path is like "/data/user/0/com.abc.pdfdevelop/app_flutter/Images/1593177139472.jpg" . what's the proper way to handle it

Comment: Please create new question with PDF issue